# How to get Z-distance for every pixel in the frame (Computer Vision)?

Tags: python, 3d, blender

I am currently doing a computer vision task and got stuck on the following problem. I need ground truth values for my sequence. I have a nice sequence where the camera moves trough my scene and captures the RGB-frames. Now, I need a corresponding frame for every RGB-frame, but instead of the RGB-values it should store the distance. I know, that you can get the total depth (euclidean distance from camera to real-world-object) by connecting the 'Depth'-output of the Render Layer Node to a File Output Node in the Compositing workspace using the EXR file format. But I just need the **Z-component of the distance to the camera** and I don't want to convert it afterwards with the camera parameters (already did it, but I need a cleaner workflow).

I stumbled upon this function: [bpy_extras.view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html#bpy_extras.view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d) , but could find almost nothing about how to use it properly. I don't know what I should give it as input.
Has anyone a solution or maybe already used the function and can explain me how i would use it in the default Blender setup (just a Cube, Camera and Light) and if it does what I expect it to do (giving the x,y,z and then I can strip the unnecessary information)?
I already tried using the [world_to_camera_view](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_extras.object_utils.html#bpy_extras.object_utils.world_to_camera_view) function, but this only works for object-parameters like vertices and not for the whole surface to create a dense map.
I also know, that you can render the scene with a Cycles material to store x,y,z in the RGB-channels, but there you only get world-coordinates and you have to change the materials after you rendered the real sequence. 
I really need just a frame with z-distance to the camera for every pixel in the frame.

I would be really grateful if someone could help me, because I've been trying to do that for days now.

Comment: This is not a computer vision problem. This is a graphics problem. Take a look [here](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc).

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at it, but could you be more specific on what should get me the desired Z-value frame there? I already looked at it, but from what I found there, it seems that they also just calculate the depth (euclidean distance) and not the z-distance.